# HighStock Graph not showing with PHP JSON

Tags: php, json, highcharts

WHY is this not working, its doing my head in.
I have taken their sample code and done the same EXACT SAME

Their JSON file http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

Mine
http://crm.vipcashback.com/system/db/mongo.php?task=count

HTML

```
<script language='javascript'>
$.getJSON('http://crm.vipcashback.com/system/db/mongo.php?task=count&callback=?', function(data) {
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container'
            },
            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },
            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
});   
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that http://crm.vipcashback.com/system/db/mongo.php?task=count&callback=? is not sending any data...

Comment: Yeah the JSON link you provided us is blank when I look at it.  The Jakester is right, `no data = no chart`